# Whois lookup via a proxy server: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, whois

I have tried this...gives me a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Proxy`. 
The getters populate the proxy and port from a text file.

```
    //Imports
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.commons.net.whois.WhoisClient;

    public void  whoisCheck(String host) {
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(getProxy(), getPort)
        Proxy useProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);

        WhoisClient whoisClient = new WhoisClient();
        whoisClient.setProxy(useProxy);
        whoisClient.connect(IANA_WHOIS_SERVER, WHOIS_PORT);
        tmpStr = whoisClient.query(host);
        whoisClient.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: There are vital parts missing in your question: the imports and a link to the WhoisClient library.

Comment: Since `setProxy()` [can't throw](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/3.3/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.java#822) it's logical that `new Proxy()` throws this (I've to guess since you didn't say where the exception is thrown). Looking into [Proxy's API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html#Proxy%28java.net.Proxy.Type,%20java.net.SocketAddress%29) we can see that "`IllegalArgumentException - when the type and the address are incompatible`". What's the address returned by `getProxy()`?

Comment: The error is thrown at whoisClient.connect(IANA_WHOIS_SERVER, WHOIS_PORT); The address returned is 23.19.34.15 and port is 8800

Answer (score 0):

`whois` is a protocol running over TCP port 43, not over HTTP/HTTPS. It has no concept of proxies.

For these two reasons, do not use an HTTP library to connect to `whois` servers, as this will never work correctly out of the box. You will create yourself too many problems. Instead, either use a specific `whois` library in your programming language, or just go basically opening a TCP socket on port 43, writing on it your query, finishing by CR+LF and reading back the server's reply as a blob of text.

If you need to hide your IP address, you need to resort to typical IP level “redirections” like a tunnel, or a SOCKS library.